# What is the best way to monitor available network bandwidth between 2 nodes?

Tags: java, network-programming, bandwidth

I need to monitor network bandwidth between two nodes. I have full access to both ends and can run servers in both ends. Can you give some clues, ideas or related links. And also the possibility of writing it using Java(Oracle) API.

**UPDATE :-**

**Can I use time and packet size to calculate a bandwidth. Something like, sending a known size (5MB) data to other node and receive it back.
Is is possible?
How mush accurate?**

Thank you.

Comment: Study this paper http://www.psc.edu/networking/papers/tcp_friendly.html

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?  Please accept it if it helped you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be hard to do this without using all of the available bandwidth of course.

Off the top of my head, you could do a large UDP broadcast between host1 and host2 and then have host2 report back to host1 what percentage of the packets made it and what the latency was between the first and the last packet.  It would have to be large enough to overflow kernel and router buffering.

If the clocks on the two servers are in sync then you could calculate latency by sending a timestamp in each packet and comparing them on the server.  Another way is just to send a couple packets and have them be immediately ack'd by the server.

Not sure what accuracy you'd get with this sort of method.  You could improve it a bit by running this test every so often to adjust for random background network load.